# Are differentiating complex functions wrt $x$ and $y$ same?

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives, solution-verification

[image: solution]

Solution verification tag because profs make mistake and I would like you guys to respectfully take a look at this solution.

If you can choose to differentiate this function of $z$ wrt $x$, then can you also differentiate wrt $y$ and get the same answer? I didn't yet learn how to differentiate complex functions (but I know how to partially differentiate). However, according to this solution, it seems like you just pick a variable and just do the partial differentiation. Is that right?

Edit: This is my prof's comment from another question related to the same question.

> The main point here is that ux and vx are enough to determine the derivative:
> $f′(z)=u_x+iv_x.$
> Using CR equations, this is equal to
> $f′(z)=v_y−iu_y$
> but you only need one of these expressions.

Okay, it clears up that the answer to my question in title is not correct. However, how is $f′(z)=v_y−iu_y$  is the derivative of the original function?

Comment: $v_y−iu_y=-if_y$ so $f_z=f'(z)=f_x=-if_y$ for analytic functions; this is clear because by defintion $f_z=(f_x-if_y)/2, f_{\bar z}=(f_x+if_y)/2$ so if $f$ analytic hence $f_{\bar z}=0$ we get $f_x=-if_y$ (C-R) and substituting in the expression for $f_z$ you get the above

Comment: Can you direct me to the proof of $f_z=f'(z)=f_x=-if_y$? I'm looking at [this](https://people.reed.edu/~jerry/311/crforms.pdf) article but I still don't understand.

Comment: Ah, I think I found it! https://faculty.etsu.edu/gardnerr/5337/Beamer-Proofs/Proofs-Brown-Churchill-2-21.pdf